# Targeting lower SDK version in android

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

am making an app which stores and retrieves images from the user's storage directory. My app crashes on **Marshmallow** devices whenever any file related action is performed.

When I built my app I set the **targetSdkVersion** to **23** in gradle build and now the app is completed and works fine on all **pre-Marshmallow** devices.

I have noticed if I set the **targetSdkVersion** to **21** the app works fine on Marshmallow too, so is it okay to set it to 21 or it has any negative consequences ??

Comment: You should always put the targetSdkVersion on the current maximum, this should not affect how your application behaves. Only minSdkVersion should actually do something.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace from the crash?

Comment: Targetting 23 you have to manage the new runtime permissions for all devices with api 23+

Comment: should i set 21 as target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **targetSdkVersion 23** you have to manage the [runtime permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for all devices with api 23+.

Using **targetSdkVersion 22 or lower** you don't have to manage the [runtime permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) but pay attention because in all devices with api 23+ users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level.

Comment: how can they revoke ?

Comment: In the settings menu -> App -> permissions

Comment: ohh that, am pretty sure my app users are not gonna be that much advanced! Thanx any way.